# Backbone, not "this.el" wrapping

Tags: backbone.js

I do an extensive use of *templates*, and I like to use *full contained* templates. I mean that I want to see in the *template* code all the DOM elements including the *root* one, like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-card">
  <div class="card box" id="card-<%= id %>">
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
    <div><%= name %></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

But what Backbone likes is having a *template* like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-card">
  <h2><%= title %></h2>
  <div><%= name %></div>
</script>
```

And defining the *root* element and its attributes in the JS code. What I think is ugly and confusing.

So, *any good way to avoiding my Backbone View to wrapper my template with an extra DOM element?*

I have been checking this issue thread: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/546 and I understand there is not any official way to do it.. but maybe you can recommend me a non official way.

Comment: What about rendering the full template and using setElement?

Comment: @nikoshr, please elaborate a minimal answer I'll accept it. It is working in my experiment. The only problem is that I have to use the `setElement()` into the `render()` method after the _template_ has been rendered.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer as soon as I get my hands on a real keyboard

Comment: What's the problem with wrapping your template in an empty DIV? Then you can use Backbone properly, while still maintaining your full contained template

Comment: The DOM structure changes completely what affects to CSS selectors. And the most important: I feel ill seeing all these _zombie_ div elements around. Also in my last special case I'm working with _draggable_ elements and the extra `divs` are adding weird behavior.

Comment: a pre +1 for @nikoshr. I have used that method before when there are a non trivial amount of attributes on the outer element. If it were a simple element with a class (most common case), I would prefer to use/set the el and className props.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659597/backbonejs-view-self-template-replacewith-and-events

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`view.setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) to render a complete template and use it as the view element.

> **setElement** *view.setElement(element)*
>   If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use setElement, which will
>   also create the cached $el reference and move the view's delegated
>   events from the old element to the new one

Two points you have to account for:

1. `setElement` calls `undelegateEvents`, taking care of the view events, but be careful to remove all other events you might have set yourself.
2. `setElement` doesn't inject the element into the DOM, you have to handle that yourself.

That said, your view could look like this

```js
var FullTemplateView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {
        var html, $oldel = this.$el, $newel;

        html = /**however you build your html : by a template, hardcoded, ... **/;
        $newel = $(html);

        // rebind and replace the element in the view
        this.setElement($newel);

        // reinject the element in the DOM
        $oldel.replaceWith($newel);

        return this;
    }
});
```

And a working example to play with http://jsfiddle.net/gNBLV/7/

Comment: and what if the template does not have a main element?

http://jsfiddle.net/Antonimo/vrQzF/5/

Comment: I was so sure this would fix it for me but it didnt. What did though is using `insertAfter` instead of `replaceWith`. Using it like so: `this.render().$el.insertAfter($oldel);` will do exactly as you would expect from replaceWith but also preserving all events (so long as you do something like `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`  inside `render()`

Comment: That's the right way to render (specifically dynamic list items) as it makes the render method idempotent.

Comment: Note that `setElement` can take a html string directly and it takes care of making a jQuery object out of it.

Comment: @Hontoni If your template doesn't have a root element, that's defying the point here. You should just use the one created by Backbone (the default or overriden `tagName`) or encapsulate your template inside a main element. Backbone views *must* be a unique element and can't be arrays of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also define a view's **tagName** as a function and create a class like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: '#my-template',
   tagName: function() {
     // inspect the template to retrieve the tag name
   },
   render: function() {
     // render the template and append its contents to the current element
   }
});
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsbin.com/doduvo/latest/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: That's hackish at best, and relies on stripping the first tag of the template by only appending its children...

Comment: @EmileBergeron Why hackish? my solution is not defining any code, just a convention that you must implement however fits you best. The code in the example is not meant to be a universal solution. In the other hand I believe using "setElement" in side the "render" method will hurt performance.

Comment: It's just a worse version of `this.setElement(this.template)`. I can't think of a situation where this solution could be better and/or more efficient.

Comment: You have not understand it at all. The hole point is not to use `setElement` inside the render method because this is rewiring all the event listeners! The render method in my example is just replacing the view contents.

Comment: `setElement` takes care of undelegating and re-delagating DOM events ([annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-162)). [Here](http://jsbin.com/jevetot/3/edit?html,js,output)'s your modified example, it's all it takes with `setElement`.

Comment: I even added a new button to re-render and prove that rendering is idempotent with setElement.

Comment: Exactly as you said `setElement` is undelegating and re-delagating DOM events in each call to `render` which is not ideal for performance.
[here](http://jsbin.com/femihu/2/edit?html,js,output) you have both versions and you can see the difference is considerable.

Comment: The test is a little irrelevant since we rarely re-render a view a 1000 times, but this **proved you right** in that `setElement` is a little slower. But that difference becomes even more irrelevant when rendering a 1000 **new** views, as in a list, which is a more practical use-case. If you're after performance, I think I would still avoid this technique and just use what backbone is providing (setting the _ugly_ `tagName`, `attributes`, `className`). And other than that, the regex could fail since you're not parsing HTML, but a mustache template string.

Comment: I like that you took the time to prove your point with nice tests!

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone.Decarative.Views](https://github.com/hashchange/backbone.declarative.views) provides you with an alternative way to do this, without having to rely on `setElement`. For more, check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232975/508355).