# Rendering subview inside view creates an extra div

Tags: html, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I have a backbone view, called container

```
ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#containerTmpl').html()),
    //this.$el.append(subview.render().el);
}
```

Then there is a subview

```
PictureView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#photoTmpl').html())
}
```

My templates look like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="containerTmpl">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="photoTmpl">
  <div class="photo-container">
    <img src="<?- url ?>" alt="" />
  </div>
</script>
```

When this actually renders on the page I see **one extra Div** created and my structure looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>     <!--Where is this extra div coming from??? -->      
        <div class="photo-container">
            <img/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594961/backbone-not-this-el-wrapping ?

Comment: See above comment for solution. The reason behind your extra `div` element is that Backbone will automatically create an element if you don't give it one when instantiating a view. The default type being a `div` element, you have an extra one.

Comment: can you please provide an example code so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the tagName of each view, if you don't want it to save everything under a div element.

Sorry, i'll correct this. Should be like:

Something like:

```
Picture = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#photoTmpl').html()),
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'photo-container'
});
```

And the template

```
<script type="text/template" id="photoTmpl">
    <img src="<?- url ?>" alt="" />
</script>
```

Hope it helps