# Append view without container - backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm creating with backbone a view for a `meta tag` that I need it to be in the `head` for obvious reasons.

The problem is that the output result I'm having is the `meta` inside another `meta` container. So I get this:

```
<head>
    <meta>
         <meta name="description" content="The description of the meta">
    </meta>
</head>
```

I'm creating it like this:

```
    var Useroptions = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(d){
            this.data = d.obj.data;
            this.template = Handlebars.compile(d.obj.template);
            d.parent.model.bind('change:category', this.openCategory);
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.data))
        }
    })

    var App = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : 'body',
        model : new AppModel(),
        initialize : function(){
            var _this = this;
            this.useroptions = new Useroptions({
                obj : _app_.useroptions,
                el : $('<meta />').appendTo('head'),
                parent : this
            });
    });
```

Any idea on how to get this without the container so my output would be:

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="The description of the meta">
</head>
```

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594961/backbone-not-this-el-wrapping/11598543#11598543 ?

Comment: @nikoshr thanks. But do I have to remove the `el : $('<meta />').appendTo('head')` in the `App`?

Comment: No, the render method I linked would replace it instead of appending to it.

Comment: I replaced my `render: function` with your method. And replaced `html= /**however you build your html **/;` with `html= "<meta />";` It outputs in the `head` just the tag: `<meta>` without any content :/

Comment: Well, if you set your HTML to an empty meta, you will get `<head><meta /></head>`. Try `html = '<meta name="description" content="The description of the meta">'`; . And here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/axnxe61z/

Comment: I see, the thing is that i'm getting the meta description of a custom field from a `view > template`. I can't hardcode it there because I want the user to be able to change it from the content editor.

Comment: Then `html = this.template(this.data)`

Comment: Wow man, it works! thank you very much. Add it as an answer so I can award it to you :)

Comment: I'll mark your question as a duplicate if you don't mind, the answer is the same if you omit a few wrinkles we worked out in the comments.